# launchd ExitTimeOut doesn't work

Tags: macos, timeout, launchd, launchdagent

I Have a plist file with some job:

```
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>StartScript</string>
    <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Users/ie54553/Desktop/script.sh</string>

    <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>10</integer>

    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>
        <integer>30</integer>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/Out.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/Err.log</string>
</dict>
```

The problem is that the script.sh is being executed each 10 sec over and over, and doesn't stop the execution after the ExitTimeOut time (30 sec)

From some reason the ExitTimeOut doesnt work ...

Any idea how I can kill the job / execution ?

Tanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not what `ExitTimeOut` is for. When unloading a job `launchd` sends the signal `SIGTERM` to the process. Should the job not terminate within `ExitTimeOut` seconds (20 seconds by default), launchd will send signal `SIGKILL` to force-quit it.

`launchd` has no means to terminate a job after a given timeout.

Comment: So there is no way to kill the job ?

Comment: No. This is left to the script/program.